# sql query issue in record

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I am getting problem in record using following query

```
SELECT user_id FROM temp 
  WHERE 
    (value = 1 AND field_id = 11) AND 
    value = 1 AND field_id = 12
```

Here is the table. 
[image: Table]

I should get record of 101 user_id.

Any one idea on this?

Comment: Please do not use pictures to post text. Instead convert it into text.

Comment: Did you mean `OR` instead of `AND`. As it stands you are currently filtering for `field_id=11 and field_id=12`.

Comment: Please always prepare a complete example when asking for debugging help. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to *aggregate* by user:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM temp
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING
    SUM(CASE WHEN value = 1 AND field_id = 11 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
    SUM(CASE WHEN value = 1 AND field_id = 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this sql select DISTINCT user_id from temp where value=1 and (field_id=12 or field_id=11)

Comment: Please edit your answer. Format the code as code, and describe what it does.

Comment: In value column it will not display always 1. It can be change for each condition like field_id = 12 and value= 2

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `where` clause :

```
select user_id
from table t
where value = 1 and field_id in (11, 12)
group by user_id
having count(distinct field_id) = 2;
```